# MySQL: how to use audit_log plugin to audit user modification

Tags: mysql, audit

I am trying to audit any user modification action (create user/alter user/drop user/rename user) on a MySQL Enterprise server 5.7.24.

I have installed the audit_log plugin following the
 [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/audit-log-installation.html),
and tried to configure the filter with a few approaches.

First, I tried to use
[general](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/audit-log-filter-definitions.html#audit-log-general-event-fields)

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_filter('user_modification', 
'{
  "filter": {
    "class": {
    "name": "general",
      "event": {
        "name": "status",
        "log": {
          "field": { "name": "general_sql_command.str", "value": "create_user" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}') as RESULT;
```

and assigned the filter to everyone but no luck, it doesn't generate any audit log when I tried to create user

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_user('%', 'user_modification');
```

I also tried to swap a few things in the same filter, no luck

- swap 'create user' with full instrument name 'statement/sql/create_user'
- swap 'general_sql_command.str' with 'general_command.str'

Next, I tried to use '[table_access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/audit-log-filter-definitions.html#audit-log-table-access-event-fields)' instead of '[general](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/audit-log-filter-definitions.html#audit-log-general-event-fields)', hopeful it will capture any movement on mysql.user table, but still not luck

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_filter('user_modification', 
'{
  "filter": {
    "class": [
      {
        "name": "table_access",
        "event": {
          "name": [ "read", "insert", "delete", "update" ],
          "log": {
            "field": { "name": "table_database.str", "value": "mysql"},
            "field": { "name": "table_name.str", "value": "user"}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}') as RESULT;
```

Just in case I missed out on any step during installation, I created another filter for test and the result is positive.

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_filter('connection', 
'{
  "filter": {
    "class": { "name": "connection" }
  }
}');
```

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_user('%', 'connection');
```

Now I am totally puzzled, can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for it, you just need to relogin to database... so audit_log will be able to capture the action.

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_filter('user_modification', 
'{
  "filter": {
    "class": {
    "name": "general",
      "event": {
        "name": "status",
        "log": {
          "field": { "name": "general_sql_command.str", "value": "create_user" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}') as RESULT;
```

```
SELECT audit_log_filter_set_user('%', 'user_modification');
```